# In Laravel 8, I have errors in the console: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'index_2': needed in a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8, rollback

I have a problem with the rollback from my Laravel application. The problem is when I am trying to rollback the migration:

```bash
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

I have errors in the console:

```
General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'index_2': needed in a foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `inventory_boms` drop index `index_2`)
```

Below I'm showing my migration class:

```php
public function up()
    {
      Schema::table('inventory_boms', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->index(['team_id','deleted_at'],"index_1")->unique();
         $table->index(['team_id','deleted_at','inventory_product_variant_id'],"index_2")->unique();
        }); 
    }

   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('inventory_boms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $sm = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
            $indexesFound = $sm->listTableIndexes('inventory_boms');
            if(array_key_exists("index_1", $indexesFound))  $table->dropIndex('index_1');
            if(array_key_exists("index_2", $indexesFound))  $table->dropIndex('index_2');
        });
    }
```

The migration rollback problem needs to be resolved.

Comment: the order of your migration is wrong and the index_2 is used as a foreign key in prior migration according to the migration names (dates). drop the foreign key before dropping the index.